# Websocket not able to open the port on Ubuntu

Tags: symfony, websocket, ubuntu-15.10

I am using websocket [bundle](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) on a symfony based web portal while everything seems to work on localhost things break down when I moved the portal on production server.

On localhost the host i am using is `127.0.0.1` and the port is `8080` so when I moved to the production I had to change the ip to the production ip and I had to then tell ubuntu server to open the port 8080 using the following command

`sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp` which gave me the output of

```
Rule added 
Rule added (v6)
```

I then ran the command `sudo ufw status` to see if the port has been added in firewall and i can see that it is

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However the error remains

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://111.222.333.44:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I also tried the command `telnet 111.222.333.44 8080` and this gives me the following error

```
Trying 111.222.333.44...
telnet: connect to address 111.222.333.44: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

So this tells me the port `8080` is not open, what commands do I need to use to open this? I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: So what ip address and port you're listening to? Could you confirm that with `netstat`?

Comment: i need to be able to listen to ip lets suppose `127.0.0.1` and port `8080`

Comment: What ip address and port your application is currently listening to?

Comment: it seems to be listening to `127.0.0.1` and port `80`

Comment: i think if i can get it to listen to port `8080` on `127.0.0.1` when that should do the work

Comment: That will not - `127.0.0.1` is a local interface and is not available from outside. You must either bind to the external ip address or listen on all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115935/discussion-between-baig-and-zerkms).

Answer (score -2):

Try opening port 6001, this is the port that websockets use:

```
sudo ufw allow 6001/tcp
```